# Correct synchronization of reads and writes to ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, concurrency, servlets

I am writing a web application (Servlets, JDBC, no Spring - for learning purposes) that accepts orders from customers, while registered couriers can choose which one of these orders they want to deliver. Several couriers may want to deliver the same order, in which case the system creates a contest and sets the deadline for every willing courier to apply. When the time is up, the system selects the winner and deletes the contest.

I made one class that takes care of all contest logic and chose to make a `static final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Queue<Courier>>` for holding all contests. I am also using a `final static ScheduledExecutorService` to set timers for every contest.

The two most important methods are `addOrCreate()` and `withdraw()` (while the timer is on and selection process hasn't started yet, any candidate can change his mind and withdraw his application). Since there will be a harsh multithreaded environment with many concurrent requests from different couriers, I need to make sure that these methods work in a predictable, thread-safe manner. I am particularly concerned with `withdraw()` method, as I use synchronization on a map bucket, and I am not sure if that is the best solution.

Please advise whether the following implementation is acceptable.

```
public class ContestManager 
{
    private static final ConcurrentMap<Long, Queue<Courier>> ALL_CONTESTS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService THREAD_POOL = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(16);

    /**
     * Add courier to an existing contest or create new contest with courier
     */
    public static void addOrCreate(final Long orderId, final Courier courier) {
        if (ALL_CONTESTS.get(orderId) == null) {
            ALL_CONTESTS.computeIfAbsent(orderId, o -> {
                // Create new contest
                final Queue<Courier> contest = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

                // Set selection process delay
                THREAD_POOL.schedule(() -> {
                    updateDataBase(orderId, applySelectionLogic(contest));
                    // Remove entry from the map
                    ALL_CONTESTS.remove(orderId);
                }, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

                // Store contest in map
                return contest;
            });
        }

        // Add courier to contest
        ALL_CONTESTS.get(orderId).offer(courier);
    }

    /**
     * Withdraw courier from an existing contest
     */
    public static void withdraw(Long orderId, Courier courier) {
        if (ALL_CONTESTS.get(orderId) != null) {
            synchronized (ALL_CONTESTS.get(orderId)) {
                if (ALL_CONTESTS.get(orderId) != null) {
                    ALL_CONTESTS.get(orderId).remove(courier);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Courier applySelectionLogic(Queue<Courier> queue) {
        // Selection logic
    }

    private static void updateDataBase(Long orderId, Courier courier) {
        // Update database  
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Review, in the withdraw method the synchronized is really necessary ?

Comment: @jimmayhem if you see something in the question code that can be improved, please write an answer instead of editing.

Answer (score 1):

- Naming:  Uppercase names are usually reserved for constants.
- addOrCreate :
  Why are you checking orderId twice? computeIfAbsent will check if the orderid is there, there is no performance or any other gain in doing it beforehand. Then you are getting it for the third time, however your function is not atomic. So it is possible that it is not going to be there at this point and your method will throw a null pointer exception. It is also possible that the callback is called just after your final get call. In that case you will just silently lose the courier. Your schedule code just schedules a task and forgets about it. It means that among other things, you can not restart your server without losing the queue.
- withdraw :
  You are checking orderid three times here for no reason. When your second call happens, the value might already gone and your synchronize will fail. Also, not sure what this synchronize synchronizes with. Since it is the only statement here, it can only synchronize with itself, however, there is little need to synchronize a single call to a concurrent collection. The third get is equally unnneded since remove succeeds if the item does not exist.